# Switching to Linux for the first time

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, 22.04, lts, 22.10

I'm going to switch to Ubuntu from the Windows operating system for the first time. Should I install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic ?
Thanks...

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, the actual version number is an LTS version with 5 years support. The Ubuntu 22.10 version only has 9 months support. You decide but I would go LTS.

Comment: Currently it is impossible to truly answer your question since we know nothing except that you never used Linux before. Going just by that I would recommend using 22.04 since it is LTS: Long time support. Using LTS allows you to upgrade to the newest linux version less often and therefore is less "annoying" for the casual user.

Comment: I used to upgrade every new version, now I only upgrade every LTS version.

Comment: You could spend an afternoon trying them both, but you won't notice much difference. Do your research on the difference between LTS and non-LTS releases of Ubuntu. That will determine your preference. If you change your mind, simply backup your data and install the other.

Comment: It depends a little on your hardware. If it works with Ubuntu 22.04 - use the LTS version. As @Joepie Es pointed out: Ubuntu has different flavours, that make up the desktop.  If you are not comfortable with Ubuntu's Gnome desktop try XFCE (Xubuntu) or KDE (Kubuntu)

Comment: The 2022-October (22.10) release will of course have newer software than the 2022-April (22.04) release, but 22.10 is the first of the cycle that concludes with 24.04 in 2024-April; ie. you're on the regular upgrade cycle (*every 6-9 months*) to get the latest of everything, and can't step off that until you reach the next LTS (2024-April or 24.04) & can decide again if you stay on the LTS path (*upgrading LTS to next LTS*) or go again on the 6-9 month upgrade cycle to get the latest.  Your needs & capabilities decide which is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try Ubuntu and see if all your hardware works and if you can use the software you need to use.
 If all works for you I would recommend (, for the time being at least ) install Ubuntu besides ( in another partition ) your Windows installation. This is called dual boot. You can read and write to NTFS partitions with Ubuntu, no problem. So you still have access to all your files and documents. 
Make a backup of these anyway!! 
If you are used to using Ubuntu ( or any other Linux distribution for that matter ) and don't need to use any Windows specific software, you can always delete your Windows partition if you like and add the unallocated space to your Ubuntu ( / ) partition or your /home partition. 
I would go for 22.04 for Long Term Support.
By the way, do you know that Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu have a more Windows-like desktop environment than the ( original ) Ubuntu? They use an Application Launcher more like the Windows Start menu. Under the hood they work the same though. ( Just for information. Not trying to talk you out of Ubuntu or anything. )